# Access Instance Variable from another class for GUI in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4

In my project I have 2 Classes. I have a problem in accessing variables from 2nd class. The code structure is as follows.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
       -------------------
       -------------------
       -------------------
       -------------------
       -------------------
    def function1(self):
       self.variable_I_wanna_share="XXXX"
       -------------------
       -------------------
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_Dialog):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       -------------------
       -------------------
       -------------------
       -------------------

    def function2(self):
       *Want to get that variable to here*
       -------------------
```

I inherited 2nd class from 1st class But it didn't work. Any one can help me to figure this out?
**Note - 1st and 2nd classes are generated from pyuic4(pyqt) separately**
Thank you.

Comment: You are using an instance variable, not a class variable, so you have to *access it from an instance.* Anyway, as written `self.variable_I_wannna_share` will not exist until you use `function1`. You may need to do that in `function2` when you inherit from it.

Comment: like `self.variable_I_wanna_share` on function 2?

Comment: How about using a class variable ? for example in your `__init__()` ?

Comment: I typed `self.variable_I_wanna_share` on function2. Got an error `AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'variable_I_wanna_share'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been suggested I think you can archive what you want using class variables.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    variable_I_wanna_share = "XXXX"
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        pass
    def function1(self):
       Ui_Dialog.variable_I_wanna_share="YYYY"

class Ui_MainWindow(Ui_Dialog):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        pass
    def function2(self):
        #accessing class variable
        print(Ui_Dialog.variable_I_wanna_share)

dialog=Ui_Dialog()

window=Ui_MainWindow()
```

And here is the class var:

```
In [3]: window.function2()
XXXX
```

you can modify the class var with your function1 from any of the instances

```
In [4]: window.function1()

In [5]: window.function2()
YYYY
```

you can also access modify the class var form the instances

```
In [6]: window.variable_I_wanna_share
Out[6]: 'YYYY'

In [7]: dialog.variable_I_wanna_share
Out[7]: 'YYYY'
```

just remember that if you modify a class var referring it from a instance you will only modify it for that instance.

```
In [8]: dialog.variable_I_wanna_share="ZZZZ"

In [9]: window.variable_I_wanna_share
Out[9]: 'YYYY'

In [10]: dialog.variable_I_wanna_share
Out[10]: 'ZZZZ'
```